# Splitting formulas for spectral flows

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, index-theory

I'm asking if there are splitting formulas for equivariant spectral flow and higher spectral flow (of Dai-Zhang) for paths of Dirac operators, concerning gluing together two smooth compact Spinc manifolds along their common boundary.

Thank you